# Add sequence number next to text in excel in the same cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel file containing names of students. How can i add an auto sequential number next to username.

For example,

```
John1
Bob2
Chris3
and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the names and run this macro:

```
Sub dural()
    i = 1
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = r.Value & i
        i = i + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```